# How to read a matrix cell by cell (while loop nested in two for loops) in R?

Tags: r

I need to extract the length and strength (amount) of rain showers from a data set. The data is a matrix where each row includes the data for one day. The data is split in 5min intervals, so each column is for one 5 min interval (288 columns). I now want to find the beginning of a rain shower and sum the amount and length until it stops. Because rain-showers can extend into the next day, I need to be able to keep summing in the next row. For my loops to work, I added the last column to the front of the matrix, but moved it one row down (basically adding the last cell of the previous row to the front of the next):

```
# create an example matrix
Dat=matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
a=c(0,0,0,0,1) # last column added to the front
b=c(0,0,0,1,0) # last column
Dat=cbind(a,Dat,b,b)
e=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) # just another row
Dat=rbind(Dat,e)
```

Matrix looks like this

```
0 1  6 11 16 21 0 0   
0 2  7 12 17 22 0 0  
0 3  8 13 18 23 0 0  
0 4  9 14 19 24 1 1  
1 5 10 15 20 25 0 0  
0 0  0  0  0  0 0 0
```

now I run my code:

```
Rain=0
Length=0
results=data.frame()
i=1
j=2

for (i in 1:nrow(Dat)) { # rows
for (j in 2:ncol(Dat)) {  # cols

  if(Dat[i,j]==0){   # if there is no rain 
    print(c(i,j,"if"))
    j=j+1            # move on to next cell
       if(j==(ncol(Dat)+1)){ # at the end of the line,move to the next row
      i=i+1
      j=2 
    }} 
  else {print(c(i,j,"else")) # if there is rain

    if (Dat[i,j-1]==0) { # check if there was no rain before => start of rain)
     Rain=0 
     Length=0 
     while(Dat[i,j]>0){  # while it is raining, add up
        print(c(i,j,"while"))
        Rain=Rain+Dat[i,j]
        Length=Length+5
        j=j+1        # move to next cell
        if(j==(ncol(Dat)+1)){ # at the end of a row, move to the beginning of the next
         i=i+1
         j=2
         }
      }
      results_vector=c(Rain,Length) # save the results
      results=rbind(results, results_vector)
    }}}}
```

This works quite well (meaning the added up results are ok), however, the indexes don't seem to get handed over from the while loop to the for loops, and I couldn't find out why. So when the while loop jumps to the next line, the for loop repeats checking this line where there is no rain, see output:

```
>[1] "1"    "2"    "else"   
>[1] "1"     "2"     "while"   ** #enters while loop**  
>[1] "1"     "3"     "while"     
>[1] "1"     "4"     "while"   
>[1] "1"     "5"     "while"   
>[1] "1"     "6"     "while"   
>[1] "1"    "3"    "else"     **#exit while loop, but runs in if-else loop**   
>[1] "1"    "4"    "else"    
>[1] "1"    "5"    "else"   
>[1] "1"    "6"    "else"   
>[1] "1"  "7"  "if"  
>[1] "1"  "8"  "if"  
>[1] "2"    "2"    "else"      **# next line**  
>[1] "2"     "2"     "while"  
>[1] "2"     "3"     "while"
```

.....

> [1] "4"     "5"     "while"  **# in while loop**
>   [1] "4"     "6"     "while"
>   [1] "4"     "7"     "while"
>   [1] "4"     "8"     "while"
>   [1] "5"     "2"     "while"  **# jumps to next row correctly**
>   [1] "5"     "3"     "while"
>   [1] "5"     "4"     "while"
>   [1] "5"     "5"     "while"
>   [1] "5"     "6"     "while"
>   [1] "5"    "3"    "else"     **# repeats in if-else loop...**
>   [1] "5"    "4"    "else"
>   [1] "5"    "5"    "else"
>   [1] "5"    "6"    "else"
>   [1] "5"  "7"  "if"
>   [1] "5"  "8"  "if"
>   [1] "5"    "2"    "else"    **# repeats row 5 in if-else loop!!! Why?**
>   [1] "5"    "3"    "else"
>   [1] "5"    "4"    "else"
>   [1] "5"    "5"    "else"
>   [1] "5"    "6"    "else"
>   [1] "5"  "7"  "if"
>   [1] "5"  "8"  "if"
>   [1] "6"  "2"  "if"         **# back on track...**
>   [1] "6"  "3"  "if"

Thanks for reading to the bottom! Any help or suggestions to improve/fix this would be highly appreciated because the data sets are very large (60 years in 5min intervals for several stations).

Comment: I would suggest converting this to a `data.frame` of two columns.  One of data and the other of timestamps.  This will simplify all of your calculations dramatically.  For what its worth, a `matrix` is just a `vector` with dimensions so you could just use single number indexing', i.e.: `as.vector(t(Dat))`

Comment: Your code gives 147 for the last sum. But I believe you meant 148 (4+9+14+19+24+1+1+1+5+10+15+20+25). See my other comment in the answer below.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Thanks for the reply. 147 is correct, it is just my clumsy way of checking if it is an ongoing or new rain event by copying the last column to the front one row down (last cell of row becomes first cell of next row), so the first column doesn't count. If that makes sense.

Comment: @KG12, if 147 is correct, then our suggestions below are wrong. They give 148 for the last sum. Please make sure your definition is different for the last sum. If it is, you'll have to adapt the code provided.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, yep, already adapted my data by ignoring the first column :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about the dates and times the rain events started, I would follow the advice I gave in my comment about converting to a `data.frame`.  If not, what follows is a vectorized solution that should be fast on large data.

First convert your data to a single vector if you don't care about days.

```
dat.t <- c(t(Dat))
```

Now you can get sequences with a boolean check:

```
rain_events <- dat.t != 0
```

Using `rle` we can get the duration of each event:

```
rain_rled <- rle(rain_events)
# I'm using the fact that my values are logical.
# this is equivalent to rain_rled$values == TRUE.
rain_duration <- rain_rled$lengths[rain_rled$values]
```

Then we just need to determine amount.

```
total_rain <- cumsum(dat.t)
total_rain_shift <- c(total_rain[-1], 0)

sums <- unique(total_rain[total_rain == total_rain_shift])
rain_fall <- c(sums[1], sums[2:length(sums)] - sums[1:(length(sums)-1)])

out <- data.frame(rain_duration = rain_duration,
                  rain_fall = rain_fall)
```

There are other ways, but this is one.  You can also use info from your `rle` to determine the position where the rain started and stopped if you desire, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: This code can be simplified a little bit by using this, after `dat.t <- c(t(Dat))`: `rain_start <- (dat.t>0)&(c(0,dat.t[-length(dat.t)])==0)`. This will identify the first rain event after a zero measure. Then `aggregate(dat.t, by=list(event=cumsum(rain_start)), FUN=sum)[-1,]` will give the amount of rain for each event and `aggregate(dat.t, by=list(event=cumsum(rain_start)), FUN=function(x)sum(x>0))[-1,]` will give the number of events in each chunk. BTW, the OP code gives 147 for the last sum, but I believe this is a bug.

Comment: There are many ways my code could be cleaned up and shortened.  However, my main goal was to write readable and clear code. I find the syntax and readability of the `aggregate` function confusing and difficult to parse into words so I often use multiple lines where one might do for my own sanity.

Comment: @Justin Thank you for this. It is indeed much simpler than my loops. I would require at least the start position (day = row) of my rain event, and am still pondering on how to get that info....

Comment: you can use something like `cumsum(rain_rled$lengths)[!rain_rled$values] + 1`.  Also, if I've answered your question, please mark the check box up there so other people can see your problem is solved.

Comment: @Justin Thanks again! This helped a lot. And I learned about rle :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Thanks to you, too!